# Oracle SQL Like not working for hyphenated words

Tags: sql, oracle, search, keyword, sql-like

I have a table column that holds the description which looks like this:

```
id    description
--------------------------------------
100   ... post-doctorate ...
200   ... postdoctorate ...
300   ... post doctorate ...
```

I implemented a searching mechanism where users can search for keywords and somehow I'm having issues searching for these words. **Even though I'm using `LIKE` in my `WHERE` clause I can't seem to include all 3 rows above.**

#### Query

```
WHERE description LIKE '%post-doctorate%'
```

I would like to be able to search all 3 of them using any of the variations illustrated as my keyword.

I also looked at using `SOUNDEX` but even that doesn't work.

#### Please Note

*Kindly ignore the fact that I'm not using parameterized queries in here. I'm aware of what it is and how to use it but this was an old project I created.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A method using `like` is:

```
WHERE description LIKE '%post%doctorate%'
```

But that is much more general than you want.  So, use regular expressions:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(description, 'post[- ]?doctorate'
```

Or, if you want to allow any character to appear at most once:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(description, 'post(.)?doctorate'
```

Comment: This looks promising and I'll have to test it on Monday as I'm about to leave the office. Does your solution take into account searching using `post-doctorate`, `post doctorate`, and `postdoctorate`? Using any of those will I get all 3 rows?

Comment: @PatrickGregorio . . . All three of these will match all three of those.  The first, though will match *anything* that has "post" and "doctorate" regardless of what lurks between the two.

Comment: So that means searching for `post abcd doctorate` will still return all 3 rows?

Comment: Your first solution doesn't sound like a bad idea since the users are probably going to put in multiple keywords.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio - Depending on your environment, you may want to look into Oracle Text which provides a much more robust toolkit for text searching.  The `LIKE` option would return, for example, the string "The check was postdated.  This forced our hero to drop out of his graduate program for a year.  He always lamented the fact that he never went back to finish his doctorate".  That may be acceptable to you or that may cause you to return far more rows than you want.

Comment: The second solution, using `regexp_replace()` and the search pattern with `[- ]?`, is the "standard" solution. It matches `post` and `doctorate` optionally (`?` means 0 or 1 occurrences) separated by exactly one character, namely either - or space, and nothing else. Try that first.

Comment: @JustinCave Yeah I think that's fine for me. All it is is a keyword search. It would even be nicer if the order of the keywords won't matter.